# Pass a delegate to Hangfire generic schedule method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, scheduler, jobs, hangfire

I want to pass a delegate to Hangfire method and it throws this error:

> Anonymous functions, delegates and lambda expressions aren't supported in job method parameters: it's very hard to serialize them and all their scope in general.

This is the method with delegate.

```
public async Task ScheduleAsync(Func<IBackgroundRepository, Task<bool>> condition)
        {
            using IServiceScope scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            IBackgroundRepository backgroundRepository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBackgroundRepository>();

            bool isPassed = condition is null || await condition(backgroundRepository);
            if (isPassed is false) return;

            // do action
        }
```

And this is the invocation.

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule<EmailBackgroundService>(service => service.ScheduleAsync(condition), TimeSpan.FromDays(afterDays));
```

Comment: Can you move the condition inside the service and just return early, so the service always runs instead of only running if the condition is met?

Comment: Well yes. In general Hangfire needs to be able to serialize your delegate parameter and store it in the DB and then invoke the recurring method with it. Which is very hard or even impossible. A solution would be to just define the condition delegate inside `ScheduleAsync` and pass only the delegates parameters as parameters to `ScheduleAsync` when scheduling the task through Hangfire.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I can't, the action that has to be done always depends on that condition.

Comment: @AntonKovachev Thank you.
So with hangfire for every single logic I need to write a method to schedule ??

Comment: @RubenAlexanyan yes, that's what I'm suggesting as well. Move the code for the condition directly into the `ScheduleAsync` method, and pass in any parameters that condition needs, rather than passing the condition as a lambda.
Side note - the method you call `ScheduleAsync` actually isn't related to scheduling, that's the *implementation*. If I were writing this I'd call it `ExecuteAsync` instead

Comment: Ok, Thank you .

Comment: You could try intercepting Hangfire serialization process, serialize the Expression<Func<IBackgroundRepository, Task<bool>>> probably with a dedicated library, then intercept the deseriailization process, compile and execute the expression.
But that seems a lot of work

Comment: @jbl ok, thank you.